# Leaflet Multipolyline different Colors

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i have set up my leaflet multipolyline like this...

`window.polyline = L.polyline(createRings(allDriver.length), {color: generateRandomColor(1)}).addTo(map);`

In my case, now all the diffenrent rings now have the same one color.

Is there a way to give each ring a different random color, or do i have to make a variable for each ring? And if so, how do i make a dynamic amount of such instances?

thanks!

Comment: It is not possible to give each ring a different color, you need to split the rings in own polylines

Comment: now i tried to push the polylines to an array, that i stay dynamic in the amount of them, should be possible right?